# Determine ambient temperature as inferred by in-computer thermometers?

Tags: windows-7

Here is my feature wish list:

- Displays temperature in the office in system tray.
- Uses all available information to infer room temperature (maybe CPU, maybe GPU, maybe drive, maybe weather bureau as a fallback)

Let me make clear, this isn't Weather Bug or the like since public weather bureaus don't know how cold it is in my office, they only know that its 95 degrees outside.

The idea occurred to me because a long while ago while remoting into a workstation I notice the drive temp was way up. I thought the workstation was failing, but actually, the entire building's HVAC system was on the fritz and the building was a 10 story sauna. Since an internal thermometer could detect that, it seems plausible that it could also figure out the temperature in the office.

Comment: There are in fact USB temperature sensors ([this one](http://www.amazon.com/Huhushop-TM-Powered-Thermometer-Temperature/dp/B0054U4YKI), for instance). Have you considered buying one of these?

Comment: As Cornelius already answered this cannot be done. The room temperature measurements will be completely swamped out by the much larger and largely unpredictable amount of heat produced by all the PC components. Your best bet is to look for a thermometer that you put in the room and that can be interfaced to the computer. You'll find plenty of these if you Google "thermometer interface"

Comment: Someone post the USB/HW solution as an answer! Yeah, I thought about this some more... even if one could use statistics to work out the gap between room & component temp, the user would have to gather extensive data on room temperature. Which implies an external thermometer already exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP in a [comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/determine-ambient-temperature-as-inferred-by-in-computer-thermometers#comment14271_10265), I post mine as an answer.

---

Since using temperature sensors inside your PC is not feasible, buying an external temperature sensor, which can be connected to a PC somehow, would be the simplest and probably also the most powerful option.

A random list of sensors I found via Google:

- USB interface: [http://www.amazon.com/Huhushop-TM-Powered-Thermometer-Temperature/dp/B0054U4YKI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054U4YKI)
- WiFi interface: http://www.monnit.com/Products/Wireless-Sensors/Wi-Fi/Wi-Fi/Wireless-Temperature-Sensors
- self-built sensor with an Arduino and an WiFi interface: http://www.openhomeautomation.net/tiny-wifi-temperature-arduino/

(warning: surf and buy the products on the linked URIs at your own risk.)

Answer (score 1):

That is (almost) impossible. The temperature sensors inside a PC are placed in key locations and are not in the way of any air flow! Some may be even inside integrated circuits like processors and chipsets. Others are in thermal contact with heatsinks.

Let's say someone would design a software that can estimate ambient temperature based on the readings from that sensors. It would need a complex algorithm that would take into account the following parameters:

- the stable temperature reported when the measured device is idle
- the stable temperature when the device measured is fully stressed
- the time needed for cool down and warm up (time needed to reach the above states)
- the ambiental temperature variation that will modify sensor reported value in the above situations
- the cooling system of your PC and its current status and relationship with the device containing the temperature sensor

So this kind of software will need a very long time to be "calibrated" for each PC it is running on. Also it would have to permanently monitor system load and its variation in time.

You could try [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads). It shows all temperatures that can be measured on your PC. Can you make a correlation between those values and ambiental temperature?

Answer (score 1):

Since office condition is mentioned, I assume that you are a office staff who commutes to office daily. Assuming yourshift ends at evening and you turnoff your computer. In the evening.

The next time you start the computer will be in morning. And there is sufficient time for the computer to cool and come to ambient temprature. By first law of thermodynamics, when you start the computer the next day, all components will be initially at ambient condition. So a temprature measuremet just at starting the machine will give office temprature.

Pls. Note, the temprature of components will rise within few seconds as soon as the computer is booted.

So we need the temprature reading just at time of booting the pc.